# How to provide classified feature to a neural network

Tags: neural-network, normalization

Let say I have a feature that may have one of 4 values, 1,2,3,4. I want to provide it as a NN input, what is proper way to do that?

I can map it like 1 -> -1.0 | 2 -> -0.3 | 3 -> 0.3 | 4 -> 1.0 , or something similar to have mean of 0.0 and std near 1.0. But in this example 1 is much different than 4 compared to difference of 3 and 4, and I don't want such discrimination cos 1 and 4 are equally different to me as 3 and 4.

Another way is to have 4 features where each of them relates to a class 1,2,3,4 and has value of 1 if initial feature has value that matches it, and has value of 0 if it doesn't match it.

Like this 1 -> [1,0,0,0], 2 -> [0,1,0,0], 3 -> [0,0,1,0], 4 -> [0,0,0,1]
But I don't like here the fact that this feature gets to much weight, especially if it has many classes.

I was thinking to make separated layer just for this feature, do you have some better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your problem, the label is a **categorical** variable (you cannot infer relation between classes just from the label value) and **not** **ordinal** (value shows relation/distance between classes).

The solution that you propose:

> 1 -> [1,0,0,0], 2 -> [0,1,0,0], 3 -> [0,0,1,0], 4 -> [0,0,0,1]

is called **One-Hot Encoding**. This is one of the most popular ways of encoding the classes during preprocessing, in order to feed them to a classifier, thus I recommend you of doing so.

You mention that you are afraid that the

> feature gets to much weight

because of the number of samples in the dataset. This is called **class imbalance**. A way of circumventing it is to pre-weight your samples for your classifier, please take a look at this [method](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.class_weight.compute_class_weight.html) implementation provided by `sklearn` package.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. But I didn't quite understood the part with class imbalance. As I am familiar with it, it is when one output label has higher frequency than the other, right? How is it correlated with my problem? My concern was that if I have f.e. 3 simple regression features and one categorical which I apply OHE to, that this categorical will have more weight (if I have 4 classes in it) Meaning when regularization is being applied it will calculate 4 weights of that one feature and 3 weights of the other 3 features, which I don't like